# Get n Value from Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, json

I'm trying to iterate through a JavaScript Array and display individual object values as alerts. Basically, the array contains objects of type `person`

```
"person" : {
     "id": String,
     "name": String,
     "address": String
}
```

And my array is as follows:

```
//This is where I get my array from the code behind. It's not empty. I checked
var obj = JSON.parse(val)

obj.forEach(function (entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    //This prints the entire array and its objects
});
```

What I want is not to print the entire array, I want to print:

```
obj.forEach(function (entry) {
    console.log(entry[1].name);
    console.log(entry[1].address);
    //This prints the entire array and its objects
});
```

What changes should I apply to my code?

Comment: just get rid of those '[1]'  , as entry is already  an element of the array ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the foreach, `entry` is just a person element, use:

```
obj.forEach(function (entry) {
        console.log(entry.name);
        console.log(entry.address);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The function in .forEach can take an index and an element -

```
$.each(obj, function(index, element) {
...
});
```

So you can either use the element directly, or use the index.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not required to use vanilla JS, you can use JQuery:

```
$( obj ).each(function( index ) {
   console.log($( this ).name);
   console.log($( this ).address);
});
```

Or

```
$( obj ).each(function( index ) {
    console.log($( obj )[index].name);
    console.log($( obj )[index].address);
});
```